# MultipartEntity and Request Body

Tags: multipartform-data, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am building an HTTP client that is using MultipartEntity and a FormBodyPart to create a multipart request. However I am not clear about how to add some XML content to the request body itself. Finally the request should look like this:

```
--ejjeeffe0
request-id: 99f9a899-5e25-45fb-9faa-d92320f60f7e
content-length: 1915
Function: CORE
content-type: text/xml
request-type: data
some-other header attributes: values

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml payload here>

--ejjeeffe0
request-id: b7612e0a-b117-4ad7-a11f-2ea5a7e5fdc1
request-type: statistical_record
content-type: text/plain
content-length: 0
some-other attributes: values

--ejjeeffe0--
```

FormBodyPart does not seem to have any method to add to the body itself. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something it should be pretty trivial

```
entity.addPart(new FormBodyPart("my-text", new StringBody(somestring)));
entity.addPart(new FormBodyPart("my-data", new FileBody(somefile)));
```

Comment: the issue is that when I do this the request fails at the Server. I dont have control over the server. The server seems to reading the data from the body of the current part and not looking for a part by name. Any ideas?